# Algorithm to find number of elements in list that are minus than/equal to the current element with complexity O(nlogn)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Thanks for visiting my post!

First a brief description of the task I'm working on:
Given a list_A of integers and a list_B, for every element in list_A, insert in the same index in list_B the count of elements that are minus than or equal to the current element in all the list_A.

Practical case:
list_A = [111, 192, 171, 391, 91, 142, 31, 373, 493, 468]
list_B = [2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 3, 0, 6, 9, 8]

Difficulty:
The problem I'm facing is to write this algorithm as O(nlogn),
do you guys have some ideas?

```
 def count_min_equal_inlist(value, list_to_check):
   counter = 0
   for element in list_to_check:
      if element <= value:
        counter += 1
   return counter - 1 #minus 1 because the element itself is not to be counted

 vettore_A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
 vettore_B = [0]*len(vettore_A)
 for i in range(len(vettore_A)):
     vettore_B[i] = count_min_equal_inlist(vettore_A[i], vettore_A)
```

Comment: *"minus than or equal to"*: since a value is equal to itself, how come your expected output has a 0? That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

> ...the count of elements that are minus than or equal to the current element in all the list_A.

Yet, your code reduces that count by 1 (`count - 1`), and also the expected output shows a 0, so somehow this description is not telling the whole story. I will assume that we need the count among **all other** elements that are less than or equal to the current element.

Then you can use this logic:

- create a sorted version of the input list
- Use binary search to find the position of the last occurrence of each value in that sorted version

Implementation:

```
from bisect import bisect

def solve(list_to_check):
    sorted_list = sorted(list_to_check)
    return [bisect(sorted_list, val) - 1 for val in list_to_check]
    
list_A = [111, 192, 171, 391, 91, 142, 31, 373, 493, 468]
print(solve(list_A))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your assumption was right, the element itself is not to be counted... anyway, can you please explain how is this O(nlogn)? Thanks :)

Comment: Oh maybe I got it.. it sorts the list in O(nlogn) with sorted() and return all elements in O(nlogn) because it uses binsearch (logn) and a for cicle (n).. so the final time complexity is O(2nlogn)=O(nlogn).. am I right? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you got it right.